# C callback using a C++ template class method

Tags: c++, c, templates, callback

I'm trying to integrate a C library with callbacks into a templated C++ class.  For simplicity say the C library operates as

```
utility_class data;
callback(double input[], void* data);

void* mem;
c_library_init(mem);
c_library_data(mem, &data);
c_library_callback(mem, &callback);
c_library_action(mem);
c_library_free(mem);
```

If I had a non-templated C++ class then this would be straightforward,

```
extern "C"
void callback(double input[], void* data) {
  static_cast<example>(data)->callback_impl(input);
}

class example {
private:
  void* mem_;
public:
  example(): mem_(NULL) {
    c_library_init(mem);
    c_library_data(mem, (void*)this);
    c_library_callback(mem, &callback);
  }
  ~example {
    c_library_free(mem);
  }
  void action() {
    c_library_action(mem);
  }
  void callback_impl(double input[]) {
    ...
  }
};
```

But if `example` is templated then `callback` doesn't know to what to cast the void pointer.  Making `callback` a static class method,

```
template <class T>
class example {
private:
  void* mem_;
public:
  example(): mem_(NULL) {
    c_library_init(mem);
    c_library_data(mem, (void*)this);
    c_library_callback(mem, &example<T>::callback);
  }
  ~example {
    c_library_free(mem);
  }
  void action() {
    c_library_action(mem);
  }
  void callback_impl(double input[]) {
    ...
  }
  static void callback(double input[], void* data) {
    static_cast<example<T> >(data)->callback_impl(input);
  }
};
```

compiles, but the executable inevitable dies with a malloc error which I can only assume is because of a new/free conflict due to the lack of a proper extern.  Defining the static method out-of-line with an explicit `extern "C"` yields the same behavior.

Is there any hope?  Thanks!

*Updated:* Added the C library call to set the user data used in the callback.

Comment: Can you use `unsigned char *` instead of `void *`? what are you going to pass as the `void *` parameter?

Comment: `void*` is specified by the external C library of which I have no control.

Comment: You are attempting to `static_cast` a pointer to a value type. You should just make the cast `static_cast<example<T>* >(data)`. The mistake is also present in your non-templated 'working' version.

Answer (score 2):

How about solving this with polymorphism? With a base class like this

```
struct example_base {
   virtual void callback(double[]) = 0;
};
```

Your templated class could inherit from it like this

```
template <typename T>
struct example : public example_base {
    example() : mem_(nullptr) {
      c_library_init(mem_);
      c_library_data(mem_, this);
      c_library_callback(mem_, callback_dispatch);
   }
   void callback(double[]) override;

   void* mem_;
};
```

And the `callback` member function could be called with

```
extern "C" void callback_dispatch(double input[], void* data) {
  static_cast<example_base>(data)->callback(input);
}
```

Comment: As the virtual prevents `callback` from being static, how would I set the function pointer in the C library, `c_library_callback(mem, function_ptr);`?

Comment: I was assuming that you get `data` into the C library somehow due to your example above. Is that not the case?

Comment: Sorry, yeah, I updated the example with the missing function that sets the user data.  My above comment refers instead to the `c_library_callback` call -- if `callback` is a virtual method of `example_base` then it can't be passed to  `c_library_callback` as a function pointer.

Comment: In that case make sure that `data` is initialized to `this` in the ctor of example and use the exported C callback function. Dispatching to the overriden member function is then done by C++ in that callback.

Comment: Got it.  Unfortunately, while the pattern compiles I get the same malloc error as before.  Apparently free is being called on an address that doesn't correspond to any object in memory, even if `callback_dispatch` consists of nothing but `std::vector<double> temp(5);`.  Anyways, looks like something else is going awry!  Thanks for the help, I'll approve the answer as the pattern itself is good.

Comment: Just a guess, but is example copied somewhere? It looks like a class that should delete the implicitly generated copy and assign functions.

Comment: It is not -- the class gets allocated once and the equivalent of `example::action` immediately called .  Tracing through the code `c_library_action` calls `callback` at least once with no problem, but after one or two calls it errs out with the bad free.  I'll post a related question once the time limit is up.